# Java Facelets and session?

Tags: java, session, jsf, facelets

How can I use session for facelets ?

What's the syntax...?

I would put a code like this

```
<% String loginSession = (String)session.getAttribute("login"); %> 
<% if(loginSession != null){ %> 
    Welcome <%= session.getAttribute("firstName") %> ! 
<% }else{ %> 
    Guest 
<% } %>
```

Thanks

Comment: this is bad practice to write scriplets on xhtml facelets pages, why you want to access session on page ?  instead set data in session bean and then access it using el `#{beanName.property}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#{sessionScope.login}
```

You can't have if-s in JSF (you can with JSTL, but it has complications). Instead you can choose to render or not a component:

```
<h:outputText value="Guest" rendered="#{sessionScope.login != null}" />
```

Comment: And how can I do the test "if/else" ?

Comment: Yeah thanks guys !

What I want to do is show content is session exists... or else hide the content